# JavaScript Error on WordPress Answers

Tags: support

I figured this would be the best place to report bugs; please let me know if there's a better place/way.

I'm using the latest stable version of Chrome on Mac OSX and I get a JavaScript error on question pages. The error message is the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'initIfShown' of undefined                stub.js:1
```

This results in the answer box rendering without any buttons, without autosaves, and without the preview of the question or answer as I'm writing it. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I get no js errors in Firefox; I have not tested in any other browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the latest version of Chrome after updating, not us. Just clear your cache after the upgrade and all should be well.

Comment: I thought I had tried that. I'll have to give it another go in the morning.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. It works until I close the window. Then I need to clear the cache again. Even on pages that didn't exist the last time I was on the site. There has got to be a better way to fix this problem than telling people to clear their browser cache every time they open the site.